# Auto Generate Number in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I want to create an auto generate number which similar with auto increment for segment ID in Lot/Serial Classes, like in this picture.

[Lot/Serial Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQppo.png)

After I check the code, I notice that it uses PXLineNbr

```
    public abstract class segmentID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Int16? _SegmentID;
    [PXDBShort(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Segment Number", Enabled=false)]
    [PXLineNbr(typeof(INLotSerClass))]
    [PXDefault()]
    public virtual Int16? SegmentID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SegmentID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SegmentID = value;
        }
    }
```

After I try and apply it in my code, the auto generated number doesn't appear. So I was wandering if I miss something else. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you just wanting an incremented int number? If so as mentioned in the answers you need something to store the counter in a parent DAC... otherwise you can just use an Identity field if no parent exists or implement a numbering sequence with auto number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern I'm using for PXLineNbr is to declare a line number counter field in the master table and a line number field in the detail table. It's simple and it works. LineNbr value is computed automatically from the counter by PXLineNbr attribute.

The LineCntr field:

```
public class MasterDAC : IBqlTable
{
    #region LineCntr
    public abstract class LineCntr : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBInt]
    [PXDefault(0)]
    public virtual int? LineCntr { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

The LineNbr field:

```
public class DetailDAC : IBqlTable
{
    #region LineNbr
    public abstract class lineNbr : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXLineNbr(typeof(MasterDAC.LineCntr))]
    public virtual int? LineNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked **Example 7.1: Numbering Detail Data Records** in the **T200** training available at [Acumatica Open University](http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/development/t200-acumatica-framework-fundamentals/)? It explains in detail, how the PXLineNbr attribute should be used to automatically number detail data records.

Comment: Yes I already checked and try the T200 training, but still doesn't work. thats why I was wondering if I miss something, thanks tho